# Set image background using path

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `ReyclerView` that shows all the images on a user's phone. I only want to allow one image to be selected at a time, and when the image is selected, a border appears around that image indicating the selection.

I have prepared everything including the border that will appear around the image, however, I cant seem to find a way to apply this background to the selected image. `onPhotoClick` works, and it successfully identifies the image selected. But I'm not sure where to go from here in applying the background to only one image at a time. I only have the path.

Here is my code:

SelectFileActivity.java

```js
public class SelectFileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
  List < String > images;

  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 101;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_file);

    // Remove status bar
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Initialize content
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_gallery_images);

    // Check for permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SelectFileActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SelectFileActivity.this,
        new String[] {
          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
      loadImages();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    finish();
  }

  private void loadImages() {

    // All images will be same size
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Set the number of pictures per a row
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

    images = SelectImagesGallery.listOfImages(this);
    galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, images, new GalleryAdapter.PhotoListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPhotoClick(String path) {

        // Highlight the selected photo with a border
        Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_highlight_border);
        I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE.setBackground(highlight);

        Toast.makeText(SelectFileActivity.this, "" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Do something with the selected photo
      }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
      if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        loadImages();

      } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GalleryAdapter.java

```js
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder > {

  private Context context;
  private List < String > images;
  protected PhotoListener photoListener;

  public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List < String > images, PhotoListener photoListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.photoListener = photoListener;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(
      LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String image = images.get(position);

    // Load images to Glide
    Glide.with(context)
      .load(image)
      .transform(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(30))
      .into(holder.image);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        photoListener.onPhotoClick(image);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
  }

  public interface PhotoListener {
    void onPhotoClick(String path);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a int variable selectedPosition to store the clicked item.

Now update your onBindViewHolder to apply the background to the selected image.
You can set the position inside OnClickListener and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Code:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder > {

        //rest of the code 
        private int selectedPos = 0;
        // rest of the code

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String image = images.get(position);

    // Load images to Glide
    Glide.with(context)
      .load(image)
      .transform(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(30))
      .into(holder.image);

    if(selectedPos == position)
      holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_highlight_border);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        photoListener.onPhotoClick(image);
        selectedPos = getAdapterPosition()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
      }
    });


  }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the method getAdapterPosition() does not seem to work, it cannot be found. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Try `selectedPos = position`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use interface here since you have no reference for the selected image view in SelectFileActivity. But you can do it easily like this. Add this code in your onClickListener

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_highlight_border);
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution is selecting all the images, I just want one of them